# Python 3 BlockingScheduler killed without apparent reason

Tags: python-3.5, scheduler, python-multithreading

I am running a basic blocking scheduler and it is being killed without apparent reason. In my console, a "Killed" message appears but that's all. Any idea how I could obtain a reason as to why it was killed? My function is as simple as the one below.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

import pandas as pd
import time  

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day_of_week='mon,tue', hour=17, minute=45)
def scheduled_job():

    print("Start time: ", pd.datetime.now(), "\n")

    fct.start()

    time.sleep(100)

    fct.stop()

    print("End time: ", pd.datetime.now(), "\n\n")
    return

sched.start()
```

Comment: I was bout to ask this